# MySQL Optimization

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I trying to speed up my site and main problem on it one query (code below) that runs on almost all pages.
LIMIT changes make speed up, but I need to use LIMIT 99 :(
On 24 speed is ~ 0.06 sec.
On 100 ~ 0.105 sec.
Server restriction: subquery (SELECT video_names.name...) can't be changed to JOIN

```
SELECT `videos`.`name`, `videos`.`episodes`, `videos`.`is_ended`, `videos`.`id`, `videos`.`logo`, `videos`.`type`, `user_videos`.`episode`, 
(SELECT `video_names`.`name` 
 FROM (`video_names`) 
 WHERE `video_names`.`vid_id` = `videos`.`id` LIMIT 1) as alt_name
FROM (`videos`)
JOIN `user_videos` ON `user_videos`.`vid_id` = `videos`.`id`
WHERE `user_videos`.`user_id` = '1'
AND `user_videos`.`status` = '1'
GROUP BY `videos`.`id`
ORDER BY `last_change` desc
LIMIT 24
```

Comment: I didn't understand why subquery can't be changed to join.

Comment: on my current hosting setted limit on joins, if more than setted - site raises error :(

Comment: Which table has the column `last_change`? And can you show us an EXPLAIN plan and what indices do you have?

Comment: What error do you get? Do you mean the `"This version of MySQL does not allow LIMIT in IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subqueries"`?

Comment: Maybe you need a temporary table

Comment: "on my current hosting setted limit on joins, if more than setted - site raises error" - sorry, but I have no idea what this means. Maybe if you told us what the error was I would understand. And an EXPLAIN plan + available indexes would help too.

Comment: rollback and find error:
`The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; 
check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 
or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test all variants from StackOverflow and other sources. Top speed:

1. Query from question (time)
2. Answer ["Couldn't that work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444299/mysql-optimization/7444603#7444603) (time x2)
3. Queries without `sql_big_selects=1` (time x4.5)
4. Queries with `sql_big_selects=1` (time x5 and slower)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't that work ?

```
SELECT
  `videos`.`name`
, `videos`.`episodes`
, `videos`.`is_ended`
, `videos`.`id`
, `videos`.`logo`
, `videos`.`type`
, `user_videos`.`episode`
, `video_names`.`name`
FROM `videos`
, `user_videos`
, `video_names`
WHERE TRUE
  AND `user_videos`.`user_id` = '1'
  AND `user_videos`.`status` = '1'
  AND `videos`.`id` = `user_videos`.`vid_id`
  AND `videos`.`id` = `video_names`.`vid_id`
GROUP BY `videos`.`id`
ORDER BY `last_change` DESC
LIMIT 24
;
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't be the same query.

Comment: no speed up, but looks like its the same query - page loaded successful and all data in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
SELECT
    `v`.`name`
    , `v`.`episodes`
    , `v`.`is_ended`
    , `v`.`id`
    , `v`.`logo`
    , `v`.`type`
    , `u`.`episode`
    , `v`.`alt_name`
FROM `user_videos` `u`
JOIN (
    SELECT `videos`.*, `video_names`.`name` AS alt_name FROM `videos`
    JOIN `video_names` ON `video_names`.`vid_id` = `videos`.`id`
    GROUP BY `videos`.`id`
) `v` ON `u`.`vid_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `u`.`user_id` = '1'
AND `u`.`status` = '1'
ORDER BY `last_change` DESC
LIMIT 24;
```